# Lose focus of a text field in an HTML table for a JQuery calculation to start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML table where the user enters his Standby Start Time and Standby End Time which calculates the Hours in total and based on that, calculates the Compensatory Hours Earned. All this works.

Right now, what it does, is whenever the user enters the Start and End time, the user must lose focus of the text fields so that the hours in total and compensatory hours displays the result.

What I would like is that the user shouldn't have to lose focus of the "Standby End Time" text field - by clicking anywhere in the page - for the calculation to start.

Here is my **Code:**

```js
var numRows = 2,
  ti = 5;
var tableCount = 1;
var index = 1;

window.standBy = function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".Standby").each(function(index, stand) {
    sum += parseFloat($(stand).val());
  })

  $(".grandtotal").val(sum)
}

function calculate() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

  var hours = parseInt($(".Time2", tr).val().split(':')[0], 10) - parseInt($(".Time1", tr).val().split(':')[0], 10);
  if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
  $(".Hours", tr).val(hours);

  if (hours <= 4) $(".Standby", tr).val("0.5");
  if (hours == 4) $(".Standby", tr).val("0.5");
  if (hours > 4 && hours < 8) $(".Standby", tr).val("1");
  if (hours == 8) $(".Standby", tr).val("1");
  if (hours > 8 && hours < 12) $(".Standby", tr).val("1.5");
  if (hours == 12) $(".Standby", tr).val("1.5");
  if (hours > 12 && hours < 16) $(".Standby", tr).val("2");
  if (hours == 16) $(".Standby", tr).val("2");
  if (hours > 16 && hours < 20) $(".Standby", tr).val("2.5");
  if (hours == 20) $(".Standby", tr).val("2.5");
  if (hours > 20 && hours < 24) $(".Standby", tr).val("3");
  if (hours == 24) $(".Standby", tr).val("3");
  if (hours > 24) alert("You cannot exceed a 24 hour period.");



}
$('#table').on('change', ".Time1,.Time2", calculate);
$('#table').find(".Time1").trigger('change')


window.addTime = function() {
  tableCount++;
  $('#timeTable').clone().attr('id', "timeTable" + tableCount).appendTo('#table');
  $('#timeTable' + tableCount).find("input").val("");
  index++;
  $('#timeTable' + tableCount + ' .increment').html(tableCount);

};


$(document).on('click', 'button.removeTime', function() {
  var closestTable = $(this).closest('table');
  if (closestTable.attr('id') != "timeTable") {
    closestTable.remove();
  }
  tableCount--;
  if (tableCount < 1) {
    tableCount = 1;
  }

  standBy();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="text-center">Compensatory Time for Standby Hours Calculator</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<h3>
  Time format is in 24h
</h3>
<h6>
  <I>Example: If you want to type in "8 AM", the correct format would be: "8". <br> If you want to type in "8 PM", the correct format would be "20".</I>
</h6>

<div id="table">
  <table id="timeTable" class="tg table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed tab_logic">
    <tr class="headings">
      <th class="tg-yw41"></th>
      <th class="tg-yw41"></th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l">Standby Start Time</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l">Standby End Time</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l">Hours in total</th>
      <th class="tg-yw4l">Compensatory Hours Earned</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="increment headings">1</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l headings">
        <button class="removeTime btn btn-danger">Remove Time</button>
      </td>

      <td class="tg-yw4l headings">
        <input class="Time1 form-control input-md " value="" placeholder="Enter your start time" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l headings">
        <input class="Time2 form-control input-md" value="" placeholder="Enter your end time" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l headings">
        <input type="text" class="Hours form-control input-md" value="0" readonly="" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-yw4l headings">
        <input type="text" class="Standby form-control input-md" value="0" readonly="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>







<hr>

<button class="btn btn-success pull-left" onclick="addTime();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">Add Time</span></button>
<br>
<br>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="standBy();">Calculate Total Compensatory Hours Earned</button>

<caption>Total Compensatory Hours:</abbr>
</caption>&nbsp;
<input class="grandtotal" value="" readonly="" />
```

I also have a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32u1vuoc/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line `$('#table').on('change', ".Time1,.Time2", calculate);` to `$('#table').on('input', ".Time1,.Time2", calculate);`. On every entered character your `calculate` method will be executed.

Inside the `calculate` method you may want to check if a start and end time has been entered before you start your calculations. This will prevent the Hours In Total to display NaN.

I've updated your fiddle, this is my updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/32u1vuoc/4/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of on `change` (which happen when the `input` element gets the new value entered) you can use the `keyup` event (which will trigger your function every time the user will loose a key in the keyboard that was clicked):

```
$('#table').on('keyup', ".Time1,.Time2", calculate);
$('#table').find(".Time1").trigger('keyup')
```

Here is the update to your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/32u1vuoc/2/

Comment: Thank you very much @Dekel, this is one small detail I overlooked !